# Getting a DIV to extend all the way to the bottom of the web page using CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have a web page the content of which I would like to be focused in a center portion with a white background, some 800 pixels wide. The side of the page will be in blue.

The problem is that I don't seem to be able to extend this center div consistently down to the bottom of the page. (The page in question is [here](http://avenueriviera.fr/accueil.php).)

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor = "#1DAEEC">
        <div class = "bodyDiv">
            <div class = "accueilBanner">
                Logo and navigation items
            </div>
            <div class = "belowBanner">
                <div class = "searchBar">
                    Search bar content
                </div>
                <div class = "barredContent">
                    <div id = "rssNews">
                        News Feed
                    </div>                  
                <div id = "descriptif">
                    Text description here - very long and extends down below the lowest item on the searchBar
                </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The blue cuts off after the end of the content of the searchBar. I *suspect* the problem arises from the fact that the searchBar floats left and the barredContent is in absolute position. But there isn't much I can do to tinker the descriptif, since the rssNews floating off to the right and I need to continue having the descriptif wrap around as such :

```
 ____________ ___________________________________________________________
| Search Bar |Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem |    RSS NEWS    |
|     C      |ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum |                |
|     O      |lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem |                |
|     N      |ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum |                |
|     T      |lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem |                |
|     E      |ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum |                |
|     N      |lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum|
|     T      |ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem|____________________<--the white doesn't extend below this point (and it should) and everything below has a blue background (which it shouldn't, apart from the sides)
              lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
              ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
              lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
              ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
              lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
              ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
              lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
              ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
              lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
              ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
```

Here's my CSS:

```
html {
    max-width: 800px;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    height:100%;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
    height:100%; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    border: 0px;
}
.bodyDiv {
    min-height:100%;
    width:800px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.accueilBanner {
    max-width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.belowBanner {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 800px;
}
.searchBar {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.barredContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 73%;
}
#rssNews {
    float:right;
    width: 33%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#descriptif {
    text-align:justify;
}
```

PICTURE:

[image]

Is it possible to fix this using only CSS? Or is JavaScript necessary? If so, then what script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that .barredContent is absolute positioned.

If you change the style of .barredContent to

```
.barredContent {
float: right;
width: 73%;
}
```

it should work as you want.

You can then also remove the height and min-height style properties from your body tag and its first child element.

I hope to have helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of how you could achieve this. What you need to do is to add this to your css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Once you have added this you can now set the height of your divs to **100%** so to take the full height of the page.

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/4qq3z6gb/1/) show this in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could more easily solve this problem by putting #rssNews outside and next to .barredContent instead of inside, and adding static width to them, but, if you want a CSS-"hack", this is the only one I know of

```
.html, .body, .mydiv { height: 100%; }
```

I'm not sure if it works anymore, but if it does, remember that it used to force the scrollbar to appear because 100% height is more like 102% of what you can actually see in the browser, so you will have to reduce the height to about 98%, if not 97%. It depends on the browser.